# Using OpenID to logon using safari on iPad

Tags: bug, openid, google-openid

I can't seem to logon to stackoverflow using my Google OpenId on my iPad in safari. It does work using chrome. Clicking on the Google icon does nothing - seems as though it's not executing the javascript?